# Could someone help me with the code about EXIST and ANY?

Tags: sql

I have two tables `Suppliers` and `Products`. I was required to write a statement returns TRUE and lists the suppliers with a product price less than 20. The following statement works:

```
SELECT SupplierName
FROM Suppliers
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ProductName 
              FROM Products 
              WHERE Products.SupplierID = Suppliers.supplierID 
                AND Price < 20);
```

I rewrote it like this:

```
SELECT SupplierName
FROM Suppliers
WHERE SupplierID = ANY (SELECT SupplierID FROM Products 
                        WHERE Price < 20);
```

But this statement doesn't work. I get an error.

What is the problem?

Comment: It would help if you *show* that error. And give details about tables concerned and sample data

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Your code is testing whether `SupplierID` equals TRUE or FALSE, because that's what `ANY` returns.

Comment: @tim not so. `ANY`, which can take any comparison operator(=, <>, !=, >, >=, < or <=), returns true if any of the values is true for the operator. Eg `WHERE x > ANY (SELECT y FROM z)` returns true if x > at least one y.

Comment: @Hans Kesting I am using w3school. The error is                                                                            Error 1: could not prepare statement (1 near "SELECT": syntax error)

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Both queries produce the correct result, see https://dbfiddle.uk/rxvF73F_ Seems to me that w3school doesn't use a RDBMS which supports ANY.

Comment: [I get an error](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: @XinguiLi FYI you can edit your question to include important information. Then it doesn't get lost amongst the comments

Answer (score 2):

Use `IN`:

```
SELECT SupplierName
FROM Suppliers
WHERE SupplierID IN (
    SELECT SupplierID
    FROM Products 
    WHERE Price < 20
)
```

Or JOIN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SupplierName
FROM Products
JOIN Suppliers ON Suppliers.SupplierID = Products.SupplierID
WHERE Price < 20
```

Comment: Thank you mate. Are you able to tell what went wrong in the ANY statement?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The query with EXISTS is correct. So intention was no know why the query using ANY doesn't produce the expected result, not to replace EXISTS with IN or JOIN.

Comment: @XinguiLi what database are you using?